# How to stop users from accessing a certain mount point in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I use two different ADLS one is open for all and the other one is a secured location with only the privilege given to a few individuals.
But these privileges given through RBAC are only applicable through the Azure portal and the users are still able to access the secured ADLS through mount point setup on Azure Databricks,
Is there a way to restrict the access on this mount point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--important-information-about-dbfs-permissions) and [MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/811175/restricting-a-mount-in-databricks.html), **All users have read and write access to the objects in object storage mounted to DBFS.** We cannot restrict users from using the mount point.

You can raise feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/2efba7dc-ef24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)

However you can use Role-based access control for notebooks, clusters, jobs and tables feature by selecting Premium tier

[image]